# VB.NET - Converting a string to double and back

Tags: vb.net, double, type-conversion

I am storing a value (represented as a string originally) like this - 12345678901234.12345678912 - in a double variable. After storing, it is represented in an exponential format (with an e). How do i convert this exponential representation to the original(string) representation?

```
Dim s as string = "1234567891234567.123456789"
Dim d as Double
Double.TryParse(s, d)
Console.WriteLine(d) 'Prints 1.23456789123457E+15
```

Using Decimal solves the problem but why cant Double do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string contains 25 significant digits. `double` simply doesn't retain that amount of information. Even `decimal` can barely hold that much (28/29 digits). From the docs for [`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx):

> By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

You should read my articles on [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) for more information - they come at the topic from a C# point of view, but you're obviously using the same types from VB.

In your particular case, the *exact* `double` value closest to 1234567891234567.123456789 is just 1234567891234567 - you're losing *all* the information after the decimal point.